# Use Retrofit with another request/response protocol in Android

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, request-response

I want to use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) to adapt responses using another request/response protocol for IoT (not HTTP, but very similar in terms of architecture) in my Android application. Notably, I suppose the other protocol already has an executor, and Retrofit would come in just to adapt the request results in a type-safe fashion.

I saw that the Retrofit `Builder` function used for passing in the client is strongly coupled to OkHttp:

```
public Builder client(OkHttpClient client){...}
```

I have started looking into Retrofit's [`CallAdapter`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/CallAdapter.html) and [`CallAdapter.Factory`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/CallAdapter.Factory.html) but I do not know if they can work independently from an OkHttp client or if they can bypass this client.

**Is there a way to use Retrofit with another request/response protocol?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem rather with [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/)'s [`Call.Factory`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Call.Factory.html) and [`Call`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Call.html) interfaces.

First of all, I implemented a custom `Call.Factory`. The `newCall(Request request)` method in the `Call.Factory` is the entry point. An `okhttp3.Request`is passed into it and it returns a `Call`. Here's a high-level example:

```
override fun newCall(request: Request): Call = CustomCall(request, ...)
```

The next step is to create a custom call. For that purpose, I used the [`Call`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Call.html) interface. Most methods are quite straightforward, but something to consider is the difference between the methods `override fun enqueue(responseCallback: Callback)` and `fun execute(): Response`, which correspond respectively to non-blocking and blocking executions.

Finally it is possible to pass the custom `Call.Factory` to Retrofit with the following code:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .callFactory(customFactory)
        .build()
        .create(CustomApi::class.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit is just a nice wrapper around okHttp, but you can always [use okhttp directly](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) for your purpose

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

However, this was not the point of my question. In fact, I want to use Retrofit and replace OkHttp as the request executor/client with another protocol that is more IoT-oriented. 

I already know which protocol I want to use and already have an engine for it. The question lies in how to use this other protocol (very similar to HTTP in terms of architecture) with Retrofit.